# Python. Поиск краткого пути в графе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим имеется какой-либо граф.
По итогу я записываю его в словарь и выходит как-то так,к примеру:
{0: {1, 3}, 1: {0, 2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {0, 2}}
Точка: {Доступные пути} - соответственно.
Как организовать поиска кратчайшего пути?

С помощью этой функции у меня реализован просто поиск пути,но не краткий:

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not start in graph.keys():
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

Поиск кратчайшего пути на графе надо реализовывать не по наитию, а предварительно ознакомиться с соответствующей теорией.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_кратчайшем_пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8)

Ну, если лень учиться, то хотя-бы в интернете найти, как эту задачу предлагают решать другие, кому было не лень:

https://habr.com/ru/post/119158/

Comment: Граф невзвешенный,поэтому хабр и отпал. 
И да,я искал.

Comment: У меня просто проблема с реализацией. С теорией-то я знаком.

Comment: @Hikaharu освежите [теорию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83). Вы пытаетесь реализовать [поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83), поэтому и получается не кратчайший путь.

Comment: @Hikaharu  "Граф невзвешенный,поэтому хабр и отпал" --    нет, без изуения теории таки, очевидно,  никак.  Настолько лень учить, что прочитать, что невзвешенный граф это такой граф, в котором веса всех связей равны 1? На самом деле алгоритм для невзвешенного графа это УПРОЩЕННЫЙ граф для взвешенного.  Но можете хабр, конечно и игнорировать.